# Height change event

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor 5 inside of tabs that have a fixed height. When I type into the editor and consequently increase it's height, it gets cut off from the bottom because its in a fixed height container with `overflow: hidden`. I can call the resize method on the tabs to resize it, that's not the problem. The problem is I can't find any documentation for a resize event in CKeditor. How can I know when the height of the editor changes?

I tried the `resize` event on the contenteditable div but it doesn't fire

```
ClassicEditor.create(richEditor).then( editor => {
  // console.log( editor );
  document.querySelector('.ck-editor__editable').addEventListener('resize', () => {
    updateTabs();
  });
}).catch( error => {
  console.error( error );
});
```